# Wordpress random slow loading times using https

Tags: wordpress, https

I am in process of enabling https for a wordpress site, but when using https connection sometimes the page load will take +10 seconds with this showing in Query Monitor plugin:
[image]

If using site with http sometimes that query appears too but it doesn't timeout and loads quickly.

Comment: I would blame your webserver/php configuration which does not allow to open the connection on 443 server.

Comment: thanks @Owi, I did not have my ec2 instances elastic ip allowed from 443 port in my ec2 security group.

Comment: Would you mind if I create an answer from that comment which you will accept afterwards?

Comment: @Owi sure, go ahead

Comment: Done, the answer is added, thx!

Answer (score 0):

I would blame your webserver or PHP configuration which does not allow to open the fsockets connection on port 443.